i got net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) with laravel and firebase (fcm)
 Hello everyone , First of all you should know I am a beginner with laravel and am trying to make real-time chat for web and mobile application so we used Firebase ...
when I try to send a request for my application in Firebase to get the token I get an error in my console like net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) so here is my js code for Firebase, on the bottom of the page:


<script>
    import { getMessaging } from "./firebase/messaging";

const messaging = getMessaging(app);
        messaging.usePublicVapidKey("BN6**********");
            
function sendTokenToServer(token){
console.log(token);
}
function retreiveToken(){
            messaging.getToken().then((currentToken) => {
                if (currentToken) {
                    sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
                } else {
                    alert('You should allow notification!');
                }
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.message);
            });
        }

</script>



and in the head


<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script type="module">
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js";
import { getMessaging } from "./firebase/messaging";



    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyBcyTA3ALM********************",
        authDomain: "********************-e8645.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "********************",
        storageBucket: "********************.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "********************",
        appId: "1:********************:web:********************47ee1d8"
    };

    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

console.log(messaging);


</script>



like what i mentioned that I am a beginner and most of this code I got it from Firebase docs and YouTube tutorials , so i found some guys use const messaging = firebase.messaging(); but it's the same ,
where the wrong ??
